# How to filter keys by the value of another elements with JOLT?

Tags: json, jolt, transformer-model

I have the following input JSON:

```
{
  "2021" : [ "a", "b", "c" ],
  "2022" : [ "d", "e", "f" ],
  "2023" : [ "g", "h", "i" ],
  "2024" : [ "j", "k", "l" ],
  "2025" : [ "m", "n", "o" ],
  "year" : "2022"
}
```

And I need to filter the keys that are equal to the value of 'year'. In this case, I just need the key '2022'. Something like that:

```
{
  "results_this_year" : [ "d", "e", "f" ],
  "year" : "2022"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "year": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,&)": "&"
        },
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  // just to sort
  {
    "operation": "sort",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

**"@(2,&)": "&"** - traverses backwards up the source JSON and mapping the values ​​from the top level to the value from "year".

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).